# ASP.NET StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass attribute does not display correct style

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a CssClass that I want to set to the StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass attribute.  In the design view the menu has all of the style attributes.  But when I run it, none of the attributes are displaying.  The background is white and text is blue.
This is the CssClass:

```
.StaticMenuStyle
{
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 color: White;
 background-color: #006a54;
 border: thin outset #A9A9A9; 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This is the menu that I want to attribute to the CssClass:

```
<table class="style1" cellpadding="0px" align="left">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td id="cell_menu" valign="top">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server" CssClass="panelMenu" ScrollBars="None" >
                    <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="StaticMenuStyle">                
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Create Message"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Edit Profile"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Edit Group"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Message Report"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="Admin"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
                </asp:Panel>  
            </td>  
            <td id="cell_content" class="panelContent">
                 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </table>
```

Please ignore the multiple About.aspx pages they are placeholders.

If I add all of the individual style elements to the  it displays fine.  But I would rather put them all in a CssClass.

I also tried using  
but that does not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  Now, it is picking up the CssClass and displaying the correct style.  I guess I just needed to clean out the cache.